# How to convert XDS_ASCII.HKL to .mtz file?

Tags: computer-science

I used XDS to process a set of protein X-ray refraction data and got the XDS_ASCII.HKL file. Now I want to convert the XDS_ASCII.HKL file to a mtz file for molecular replacement in ccp4. I thought the `aimless` program can do this, so  I used the following command:

```
aimless -n HKLIN ../process-xds/XDS_ASCII.HKL HKLOUT converted.mtz
```

However, the program stuck was stuck like the following:

```
root@sun phasing]# aimless -n HKLIN ../process-xds/XDS_ASCII.HKL HKLOUT converted.mtz
 
 ###############################################################
 ###############################################################
 ###############################################################
 ### CCP4 8.0.013: AIMLESS           version 0.7.12 : 21/06/23##
 ###############################################################
 User: unknown  Run date:  1/ 8/2023 Run time: 10:04:33 


 Please reference: Collaborative Computational Project, Number 4. 2011.
 &quot;Overview of the CCP4 suite and current developments&quot;. Acta Cryst. D67, 235-242.
 as well as any specific reference in the program write-up.

==== Command line arguments ====
HKLIN ../process-xds/XDS_ASCII.HKL
HKLOUT converted.mtz
```

And the shell did not return to the prompt and no output was generated. Do you know why and how to solve the problem? Where is the `aimless` in ccp4gui? Is there any other way to convert XDS_ASCII.HKL to mtz file.

I will deeply appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Can you say a little more about what the intended use case is? Are you trying to export merged or unmerged mtzs? Do you want the data to be rescaled as Aimless would do? If you want merged data, you can use XDSCONV. For unmerged, you will likely want to use f2mtz. The CCP4 programs (f2mtz and aimless) are much easier to run through the GUI. In the GUI, you can list all the programs alphabetically by clicking the menu in the top left and selecting "Program List".